# How do I add a Javascript eventListener to a password field for browser-generated password?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, passwords

I am building a password strength measure tool. Obviously, I need to assess the password every time it changes (`onkeyup` does the trick in almost every case). Except…

Modern browsers offer to autogenerate passwords.

[image: System-generated password]

If a user accepts a browser-generated password, how do I capture that event? It's not a `keyup` (obviously). But, it's also not a `change` event. How do I detect acceptance of the system-generated password so I can update the password strength measure?

Comment: Have you tried 'input' eventListener on the password field..??

Comment: Firefox triggers an `input` event: https://jsfiddle.net/ka5zmt0u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'input' eventListner on the password field.

```
field.addEvenlistener('input', ()=>{
    //do something
})
```